# Walkthroughs for Armed Assault

Tags: arma-armed-assault

Armed Assault is a really tough game.  I was in the Army and I still think it's tough.

I'd really like a good walkthrough for Armed Assault. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: Do you mean ArmA: Armed Assault?

Comment: It was called Armed Assault in the US I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dslyecxi, a member of Shacknews, wrote an incredibly detailed guide on Arma which includes diagrams, videos, and explanations for just about everything in the entire game. You won't find a better or more detailed guide anywhere:

http://dslyecxi.com/armattp.html

He also has a glossy print version available, but be warned that this is a 168 page 8.5"x11" guide.

Comment: Good lord, thats impressive.

Comment: Yeah, Dslyecxi's enthusiasm for realistic tactical games like Arma is amazing, and his time in the military definitely helped in the writing of the guides. Bohemia Interactive even recommends his guides.